# How to conditionally show stuff if a page is a parent page or a child page?

Tags: php, wordpress

This is not for any specific page page, but any page that either has children or is a child.

I have been using this function

```
function is_parent() {
    global $post;
    $pages = get_pages("child_of=".$post->ID);
    if ($pages) return true;
}

function wpdocs_get_post_top_ancestor_id() {
    if ( ! $post = get_post() ) {
        return;
    }
    
    $top_ancestor = $post->ID;
    if ( $post->post_parent ) {
        $ancestors = array_reverse( get_post_ancestors( $post->ID ) );
        $top_ancestor = $ancestors[0];
    }
    
    return $top_ancestor;
}
```

And then in my header.php using this code

```
<?php if ( $post->post_parent || is_parent() ) { ?>
<div class="section-nav">
    <ul class="clearfix">
        <?php
            wp_list_pages( array(
            'title_li' => '',
            'include'  => wpdocs_get_post_top_ancestor_id()
            ) );

            wp_list_pages( array(
            'title_li' => '',
            'depth'    => 1,
            'child_of' => wpdocs_get_post_top_ancestor_id()
            ) );
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php 
} ?>
```

It works, but I am seeing PHP warning notices in my logs:

PHP Warning: Attempt to read property "post_parent" on null (line 1 of header.php code)

PHP Warning: Attempt to read property "ID" on null (line 3 of function code)

Comment: In header.php add `global $post;` before your if; in the functions file use `get_pages(array('child_of' => get_the_ID()))`